Angular 16 - How to search filter through all paginated pages in a data table, not just the first page of table
I have a data table that is paginated well using NgxPaginationModule. I want to search filter through my table but since the data is paginated, I only get search filter results for the current page only, instead of the entire table. I have implemented a search filter pipe for this. Any help to get this working would be highly appreciated.
My seach filter pipe
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'searchFilter'
})
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (!value) return null;
    if (!args) return value;

    args = args.toLowerCase();
    debugger;
    
    return value.filter(function(item: any) {
      return JSON.stringify(item)
       .toLowerCase()
       .includes(args);
    })
  }

}

My search bar
<div class="d-flex align-items-center position-relative my-1">
   <i class="ki-outline ki-magnifier fs-3 position-absolute ms-5"></i>
   <input type="text" data-kt-customer-table-filter="search" class="form-control w-250px ps-12 me-3" placeholder="Search..." [(ngModel)]="searchText">
</div>

My table pagination & search filter
<tbody class="fw-semibold text-gray-600">
   <tr class="odd" *ngFor="let matter of Matters | paginate: { itemsPerPage: pageSize, currentPage: page, totalItems: count } | searchFilter: searchText">           </tr>
</tbody>

My app.ts
export class AllMattersComponent {
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  response: boolean = false;
  Matters: any[] = []
  page: number = 1;
  count!: number;
  pageSize: number = 10;
  pageSizes = [10, 50, 100, 150, 250];
  searchText = '';

  ngOnInit(): void {
     this.loadMatters();
  }

  loadMatters(){
    this.apiservice.viewMatters().subscribe((res: any) => {
      if(res.status === 200){
        this.response = true;
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.Matters = res.results;
        this.count = res.count;
        this.Matters = this.Matters.map(matter => {
          return {
            ...matter,
            client_name: matter.client_person ? matter.client_person.full_name : matter.client_company ? matter.client_company.company_name : ''
          };
        });
      } else if (res.status === 400){
        this.showError(res.results.error);
        this.response = true;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
    }
 );

}

First search filter, then paginate the results.
<tbody class="fw-semibold text-gray-600">
   <tr class="odd" *ngFor="let matter of Matters | searchFilter: searchText | paginate: { itemsPerPage: pageSize, currentPage: page, totalItems: count }">...</tr>
</tbody>

Also you could set the pipe to pure, to execute the pipe only when the input searchText changes. Gives better performance, since the pipe runs lesser times.
@Pipe({
  name: 'searchFilter',
  pure: true,
})
...


@narel-murali the search is still showing data only in the first page of the data table. I have searched for data in the second page but it's coming back as empty for that search.

@CoderS This should work fine, try debugging the paginate pipe and checking if the filtered results are recevied properly

@narel-murali i have printed the items in the pipi and no data in the second page appears. I think its because the API results is paginated at 10 results per page and so the table for loop loops only has the first 10 results only.

@CoderS Could you share a stackblitz with the issue replicated along with sample data, where you explain the issue you are having, because the code seems fine, maybe the problem is how you are filtering the results. try to filter a single field instead of json strinfiy compare
